# How to fetch data from multiple url and store it in single array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, fetch-api

I have an array of Objects `filteredG`, Every single object contains some Json data about route. Objects inside **filteredG** can change frequently.  The url I want to fetch from is changing based on **route.id**. If I try to map this data it isn't getting mapped inside a single array, since I try to fetch data from multiple link. Note that, there is many to many relations between **routes** and **stoppages.**

**My code example:**

`filteredG = [{id: 1, attributes: {…}, calendarId: 0, name: 'Rupsha'}, {id: 2, attributes: {…}, calendarId: 0, name: 'Boyra'}]` this array has variable length.

```
filteredG.forEach((route) => fetch(`/api/stoppages?routeId=${route.id}`)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    data.map((stoppage) => console.log(stoppage));
  }));
```

**Result:**

this snippet is printing bunch of **stoppages** objects in the console.

What I want is to store these objects which is currently get printed in a single array. How can I make that happen?

Please help.

Comment: Can you add more informations about what is stoppage ?

Comment: @superdunck Stoppage are array of objects like routes.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand what you mean

```
const allData = filteredG.map((route) => fetch(`/api/stoppages?routeId=${route.id}`)
  .then((response) => response.json()));
const aData = Promise.all(allData).then((arrayData) =>
 arrayData.reduce((data, item) => ([...data, ...item]), []));

//result
aData.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Objects are getting repeated inside the array. Not showing the correct result. Even if route.id get changed, it's showing all objects inside the array

Answer (score 0):

if you don't care about the order in which the results get into the array, you can use this option:

```
Promise.all(filteredG.map(route =>
  fetch(`/api/stoppages?routeId=${route.id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
)).then(results => {
   ...here you map the result to an array
})
```

Comment: It is storing data in a single array. But the result doesn't change when `route.id` get changes. result expected to be shown only for the selected route.